# Image sliding right to cover text then revealing new text as it slides back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an effect I want to achieve, but I'm having trouble thinking of exactly how I could achieve it. Here are some images that show the progression of the effect I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Ycd.jpg

So essentially, I have multiple slides containing text which I want to automatically display one by one. In order to hide the current slide and show the next one, I want an image (which sits to the left of the text) to slide to the right, covering/hiding the text as it goes, and then when it slides back to its original position, the text for the next slide is shown.

So how would I go about achieving this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw idea. Maybe you can make use of `:after` and `:before` and position them so that they hide the text, making it disappear.

HTML would be something like:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="over"></div>
  <div class="text">This is some text</div>
</div>
```

And for CSS look in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zs2MU/

Maybe it will help you in your situation.

**UPD** Here is updated solution which supports multiline text http://jsfiddle.net/Zs2MU/2/